# Pattern test and replacement with pure function

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

This is a very simple question. I have an **unnamed pattern** and a test function should determine whether to perform replacement on it.

How to make the following piece of code to work:

```
{1, 2, x, 3, 4} /. _Integer?(Mod[#, 2] &) -> 1
```

where only integers that are divisible by 2 should be replaced by 1.

Incidentally, even the named pattern doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Mod` returns a number, not a truth value.

Comment: `{1, 2, x, 3, 4} /. u_Integer /; EvenQ[u] -> 1`

Answer (score 6):

The function in `PatternTest` needs to return `True` in order to lead to a pattern match.

Both

```
{1, 2, x, 3, 4} /. _Integer?(Mod[#, 2] == 0 &) -> 1
```

and

```
{1, 2, x, 3, 4} /. _Integer?EvenQ -> 1
```

work.

Comment: Sure. Silly me!